# PHP AWS Cron Job Post from Worker Tier To Server Tier URL

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, cron

What I basically would want to do is to run a PHP script in my server tier web application periodically. Inorder to do this, I've created a Worker Tier application and added following code to a cron.yaml as described in [Running cron jobs on Amazon Web Services (AWS) Elastic Beanstalk](https://medium.com/@joelennon/running-cron-jobs-on-amazon-web-services-aws-elastic-beanstalk-a41d91d1c571#.4kqotwtjx).

```
version: 1
cron:
 - name: "email-job"          # required - unique across all entries in this file
   url: "https://www.example.com/cron_test.php"              # required - does not need to be unique
   schedule: "* */10 * * *"    # required - does not need to be unique
```

According to the script, `cron_test.php` would send me an email every 10 minutes (There's nothing wrong with `cron_test.php` since it works perfectly in my browser).

Since this did not work, I've tried changing the `url` to a local one.

```
version: 1
cron:
 - name: "email-job"          # required - unique across all entries in this file
   url: "/send_mails.php"              # required - does not need to be unique
   schedule: "* */10 * * *"    # required - does not need to be unique
```

In `send_email.php` page, I made a simple redirect to my required url in the server tier like this.

```
header("Location: https://www.example.com/cron_test.php");
```

Strangely, I'm still not receiving any emails from my server tier application. When I check my logs, I could see following

```
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [18/May/2016:04:58:59 +0000] "POST /send_email.php HTTP/1.1" 302 - "-" "aws-sqsd/2.3"
```

While 302 suggests that a redirect did occur, I'm still not receiving any emails. What am I doing wrong? Is there any other way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by getting the contents of the url instead of sending the deamon to the url with the header tag:

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents("https://www.example.com/cron_test.php");
?>
```